AGGREGATE function unable to calculate on a calculated array
Let me explain you my problem:

The AGGREGATE function works well when applied to a range (A) or even to a variable based on a range (B).
However, it is unable to calculate on a calculated variable (C) or even on a calculated array (D).
This seems like an excel bug to me. If it is not a bug, at least it is an annoyance for me.
I work with very big ranges that contain unknown values (represented by #N/A). So I am kind of obliged to use AGGREGATE.
However, if a calculation has to be applied to the range before AGGREGATE is applied (in my case, multiply by 2), then I am forced to create an auxiliary range, and I try to avoid it.
Can you think of any workarounds? Am I somehow mistaken with my conclusions?

Why are you bound to AGGREGATE()? Why not include something like TOCOL() to filter out errors before using AVERAGE()? And no, it's not a bug. Unfortunately it's by design.

only 14 and larger in the first argument will allow the use of arrays.  All others require the use of ranges.

@JvdV: I usually make calculations on stock market prices.
In columns I have months (for 25 years this means, at least, 300 columns). In rows I have tickers (usually 500). 300x500 = 150,000.
I have ranges for prices, returns, alphas, betas, standard deviations...  say at least 10. 150,000x10 = 1,500,000 cells.
I use AGGREGATE on columns and on rows. If I use the TOCOL function, months and tickers are mixed up and I do not get the desired results.
In the example provided above, I used one-dimensional ranges just to make my question simpler.

Care to visualize this problem with a small set of mock-up sample data? I got a good feeling your can work your way around this with array-multiplication or implementing other functions like FILTER().

I usually use a combination of AVERAGE and FILTER( ... NOT(ISNA())), but my formulas become more and more complex. I just wanted to know if I was doing something wrong with the AGGREGATE function. But as JvdV say, it is by design.

Using TOCOL() to remove #N/A is simpler than FILTER( ... NOT(ISNA())). Therefore, today I learnt something new that I'm going to use extensively. Thank you.

For averages, could you wrap results in IFERROR(calc, ""), as for example =LET(a, A4:A15, AVERAGE(IFERROR(2*a,""))), as AVERAGE ignores logical and text values?
